# The fastest way to invert a big exact linear system

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I have a big linear system of ~ $5000$ unknowns.

It is a symbolic problem in the sense that I need to find exact solutions, but I don't have variables, everything is a number (If I represent the matrix of the system it is a matrix full of symbolic numbers, not variables).

(By the way if there is a name for "symbolic but numbers", I would appreciate to know it).

It seems to be too long for my computer, so I am asking :

- Do you think such a problem is feasible on a standard computer ?
- What are the techniques I could use to increase the speed of computation at the maximum (can I parallelize, can I do other things that I don't know to increase at the maximum the speed ?)

Note : The matrix of the problem is dense.

Comment: If the entries are integers, the best approach perhaps is [the symbolic-numeric method by Zhendong Wan](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717105001653). It can be extended to handle rationals and Gaussians.

Comment: Could you make available a sample system so we can play with it?

Comment: "symbolic numbers, not variables" Does this mean exact rationals only? Or do you have forms like `Pi`, `E` or Sqrt[2[.

Comment: @m_goldberg I have rationals numbers only. I will make an example to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I expect your exact answer will involve many rational numbers with many digits in the numerator and denominator. That will require a great deal of computation with numbers that are not machine numbers. Hence it will require a long time and a huge amount of memory, and may be impractical without using a super computer. However, you may be able settle for an answer if sufficiently high precision is used. Your best bet may be to solve something like the following instead.

```
N[equatiion,200];
```